# ASP.NET MVC doesn't call global.asax' EndRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I am trying to perform some actions at the end of every request.
I changed the Application_Start() that is generated when created new project to make a test:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    EndRequest += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.Write("fghfgh");
    };
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

The lambda won't get called. Any ideas why?

edit:
I see that they are doing similar thing in SharpArch [http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/] and it does work there...
And no, I don't want to use an HttpModule.

edit2:
The only workaround I found is to use Application_EndRequest in conjuction with a private static member of global.asax:

```
private static WebSessionStorage wss;
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...
    wss = new WebSessionStorage(this);
    //...
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wss.EndRequest(sender, e);
}
```

wss must be private because it seems like the Application_EndRequest is being called using different instance object (this). That may also be reason of my event (as described at the beginning) not being called.

Comment: You can read more about why it acts like this here: http://devhawk.net/2009/08/06/I+Hate+Globalasax.aspx

Answer (score 18):

I usually do:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

This works as expected. Don't know about the event though.

Comment: I actually pass the this instance to some object, that in turn hooks with its own handler. So I can't user the Application_EndRequest.

Comment: in Application_Start I'm doing:
    NHSession.Init(new WebSessionStorage(this));
The WebSessionManager hooks in its ctor:
    public WebSessionStorage(HttpApplication app)
        {
            app.EndRequest += Application_EndRequest;
        }

Answer (score 17):

The HttpApplication instance that is represented by your global.asax file is a single instance that only represents the *first* HttpApplication object. It is not guaranteed that this instance of the HttpApplication will be used for any other request.

You need to override the Init() method in global.asax and in *that* method hook up any events that you want:

```
public override void Init() {
    base.Init();

    EndRequest += MyEventHandler;
}
```

Please refer to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0xez8f2(VS.71).aspx) for more info on the HttpApplication object.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to do this in an HttpModule. I use an HttpModule to manage NHibernate session in an MVC app and it works perfectly. In the begin request I bind the sessionFactory to the ManagedWebSessionContext (in NHibernate but fairly undocumented) and then in the end request I commit any transactions and unbind the sessionFactory.

I think it is cleaner to separate this into an HttpModule as well.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET MVC, you need to add.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("End Request");
}
```